# Body Volume Rotation Of Shape Question

Tags: integration

I want to know if I`m following the correct step to evaluate the body volume rotation of shape.
my function is : $$y=ln(x)$$ and I want to evaluate the body volume rotation of it between
$y=0$ and $x=\frac{1}{e}$ and $x=e$.

 to evaluate it I know that I need to do $$\pi\int f(x)^2dx$$
so this is what I get : $$\pi\int ln(x)^2dx $$ let $ln(x)^2$ to be $U$ then $U'$ is $\frac{2}{x}$ and $V'$ is 1 so $V'$ is $x$.
this is the correct way to evaluate it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. I'll assume that you are rotating the region bounded by $y=0$, $x=1/e$, and $x=e$ about the $x$-axis (**the axis of rotation is important!**). Then you need to evaluate the integral:
$$
\pi \int_a^b [f(x)]^2 dx = \pi \int_{1/e}^e [\ln(x)]^2 dx
$$

To do this, you will need to use integration by parts by choosing $u=[\ln(x)]^2$ and $dv=dx$ so that $du=2\ln(x)/x$ and $v=x$ (**don't forget to use chain rule!**). This yields:
$$
\pi \int_{1/e}^e [\ln(x)]^2 dx = \pi \left[\left[x [\ln(x)]^2\right]_{1/e}^e - \int_{1/e}^e x \left( \frac{2\ln(x)}{x} \right) dx \right]
$$

Can you take it from there? **Hint:** If you don't know how to evaluate $\int \ln(x)dx$, then you will need to use integration by parts a second time.